# log4j: errors to an errorFile

Tags: log4j

I have a class which events I want to log. Say, there are 2 levels: debug and error. How can I log errors to an errorFile and debug info to a debugFile?

So that I use log4j.xml there is a filter mechanism, but it seems to work only for different categories not inside one class.

Please, help to newbie. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define and use two appender with different **Threshold** like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Error -->
    <appender name="ErrorFile"
         class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="error"/>
        <param name="file" value="log.err" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d %C.%M (%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="LogFile"
         class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="debug"/>
        <param name="file" value="log.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d %C.%M (%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="foo.bar" additivity="false">
        <level value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="ErrorFile" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="ErrorFile"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

This question is also answered in the [log4j FAQs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a2.9).

---

Just found the [LogToAppenderByLevel](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/LogToAppenderByLevel) solution ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763416/is-it-possible-to-log-only-one-level-messages-with-log4j/2763489#2763489)) which may be also helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if there is a 'debug' threshold in the LogFile, information from the 'error' level will also be in it. I need only the 'debug' info int the LogFile not 'INFO', 'WARN', 'ERROR' or 'FATAL'.

Comment: @Dmitry Have a look at the [LogToAppenderByLevel](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/LogToAppenderByLevel) solution.